# Pageshow event does not fire in jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I built a jQuery Mobile Page, which consists of several different Pages (I don't use divs but pages to load content like in a "traditional" Website.
If a page is loaded without ajax (First Page first load for example or with rel=external) the pageshow event is triggered. If a page is loaded with a jQM Ajax request, the pageshow event is not triggered, does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks in Advance
John

Comment: Place js inside page div.

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution!!

Answer (score 0):

The Solution was, as Omar stated, to put the javascript

```
$(document).on('pageshow',function(e){/* Code here */});
```

into the data-role="page" div.

Thanks!